# How do I delete the snippet from my mobile blogger page, make the images as wide as the mobile page and make the title uppercase?

Tags: blogger

I am very sorry about my lack of technical knowledge in advance. I have been playing with the HTML code of my blog for quite a while now but I know  nothing about it.
I recently allowed my blog interface to be shown with a different layout when viewed with a mobile phone on Blogger. However, I want to change this a bit because I don't like the way it looks.
I want the snippets (so the little introducing text) to go away, the titles to be uppercase and the image to fill the width of my mobile device.
I don't know if this is really hard: I already tried to Google a bit and I found a few things which I tried but none of them really worked. Google told me I had to add this, but it changed nothing on my mobile device.

`enter code here`.mobile .post-title {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

The website I am trying to change this for, is www.lemontierres.com

I am very sorry if my questions are too complicated but I'm hoping they're not, thanks for anyone's help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment or I would... But it helps to be familiar with HTML and CSS to achieve different styles for mobile devices. As an example, you would want something like this in your CSS

```
@media screen {
    Title {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
```

You would need to replace "Title" in the above with the name of the class of your HTML title objects and that should transform the text on mobile devices to uppercase. The same idea would be applied to the other changes you're trying to implement.

I'm not exactly a CSS expert, but I found the following resource for CSS on mobile devices.
[Different ways to use the @media tag](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)